# Spring Integration - Java DSL alternative for XML Validating Filter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I wonder if there is a Java DSL or at least Configuration alternative for Spring Integration's XML Validating Filter

```
<int-xml:validating-filter discard-channel=""                    1
                           id=""                                 2
                           input-channel=""                      3
                           output-channel=""                     4
                           schema-location=""                    5
                           schema-type="xml-schema"              6
                           throw-exception-on-rejection="false"  7
                           xml-validator="">                     8
    <int:poller .../>                                            9
</int-xml:validating-filter>
```

Thanks in advance for any support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference manual [suggests examining the XML schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips) to answer questions like this.

> If you are familiar with Spring Integration XML configuration already, starting with version 4.3, we provide in the XSD elements definitions the description with the pointer which target classes are used to produce beans for the adapter or gateway...

In this case...

```
<xsd:element name="validating-filter">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Configures a Consumer Endpoint for the
            'org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter'
            with an 'org.springframework.integration.xml.selector.XmlValidatingMessageSelector'
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
...
```

So, with the DSL...

```
.filter(new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(...))
```

and with java config

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "...")
public MessageFilter filter() {
    return new MessageFilter(new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(...));
}
```